# find a field via forign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

This is my table in model:

```
class Stocks(models.Model):

  user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name=_('stockname'))
  number=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=64,verbose_name=_('number'))
  suffix=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=12,verbose_name=_('uffix'))
  comment=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=264,verbose_name=_('comment'))
  price=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('price'))
  date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,verbose_name=_('date'))
  seller=models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('seller'), default='null')
```

the user field is connected to the default django User table  via forignkey

User table fields are:

```
 username
 password
 first_name
 last_name
 email
```

now I want to find email of the users which the date of their stocks are lass than specific date

this is my view

```
def allstocks_view(request):

  last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30) 
  q=Stocks.objects.all().filter(date__lte=last_month).???
```

I dont know how can i find the email

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `??? -> values_list('user__email', flat=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want emails, start from the User model.

```
User.objects.filter(stock__date__lte=last_month).values_list('email')
```